# Vaadin responsive tables

Tags: responsive-design, vaadin, vaadin7

I need to create a responsive tables in Vaadin.

In this example http://demo.vaadin.com/dashboard/#!transactions less important columns are colapsed on small screen sizes.

Is there any possibility to create responsive table without hidding columns?

Comment: What do you wish to do with the columns which don't have place onscreen? That's the big question you must first answer...

Answer (score 0):

Like Andre asked, the question really is what else would you do? You pretty much have three choices that I can come up with:

- Do nothing, which will make the table horizontally scrollable (this is also what happens in the demo at some point, before dropping column count). If you have relative sizes (expand ratios) for columns, they'll just squeeze.
- Set some columns invisible (note that you can the visible columns user selectable like in the demo, move mouse to top right corner of table to see the UI)
- Combine and shorten data with smaller screen sizes. In the demo you could for example combine city and country to one column to save some pixels or present time with a more compact formatting (like 24h time, dropping seconds, dropping year).